# Regarding getting the size of array in a hash of array structure

Tags: perl

I wrote the following Perl function

```
  sub Outputing
  { 
     my $featureMatrix = shift;
     my $indexRow = shift;
     my $fileName = "/projectworkspace/input.dat";

     open(DATA, "> $fileName");
     printf DATA "%d", $#$indexRow;
     print DATA "\n";

     my $numDataPoints = $#{$featureMatrix{$indexRow->[1]}};
     printf DATA "%d", $numDataPoints;
     print DATA "\n";

     close DATA;    
    }
```

I calling Outputing as follows:

```
Outputing($matrix, $Rows);e
```

$matrix is a hash of array, whose structure is like this

```
   my $matrix 
     = { 200 => [ 0.023, 0.035, 0.026 ], 
          110 => [ 0.012, 0.020, 0,033], 
        };
```

Rows is an array storing the sorted key of matrix, it is obtained as follows

```
my @Rows = sort keys %matrix;
```

both matrix and Rows are used as parameters passed to Outputing.

The printed out $numDataPoints is -1, which is not correct? I do not know which might be the reason that causes this problem? If we use the above example, and assume $indexRow->[1]=110, then $numDataPoints should be 2. I am not sure whether the `$#{$featureMatrix{$indexRow->[1]}};` is the correct way to get the size of this array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you've included all the relevant code, this:

```
my @indexRow = sort keys %featureMatrix;
```

should be this:

```
my @indexRow = sort keys %$featureMatrix;
```

and this:

```
     my $numDataPoints = $#{$featureMatrix{$indexRow->[1]}};
```

should be this:

```
     my $numDataPoints = $#{$featureMatrix->{$indexRow->[1]}};
```

That is, the problem is that in some places, you're using a hash named `%featureMatrix`, and in others, you're using a hashref named `$featureMatrix` that refers to an anonymous hash.

You should be using `use warnings` and `use strict` to prevent such mistakes: those would have prevented you from using `%featureMatrix` when you've only declared `$featureMatrix`. (Actually, `use warnings` might not help in this case — it could detect if you used `%featureMatrix` exactly once, but in your case, you use it a few times — but `use strict` would almost certainly have helped.)

Comment: Thanks, but I still not very clear about this. First, my @indexRow = sort keys %featureMatrix; was used outside the function of "Outputing" rather than inside the "Outputing". The variable name I used may cause some confusion. I will edit my original post.

Comment: I just edited my original post. Does that affect your answer? In accordance with your answer, I should have written my @Rows = sort keys %$matrix;

Comment: @user785099: Are you familiar with the difference between `my $featureMatrix = { ... }` and `my %featureMatrix = ( ... )`? Your question says you're using the former, but various parts of your code would only work if you were using the latter.

Comment: can you elaborate more on the difference between my $featureMatrix = { ... } and my %featureMatrix = ( ... ).

Comment: @user785099: `my %featureMatrix = ( ... )` creates a hash named `%featureMatrix`. Its elements can be referred to with the notation `$featureMatrix{'...'}`. `my $featureMatrix = { ... }` creates an anonymous hash, and a reference to that hash. The reference is named `$featureMatrix`. The hash can be referred to with the notation `@$featureMatrix`, and its elements can be referred to with the notation `$featureMatrix->{'...'}`.